# Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle

Tags: flutter, aar

I Create a flutter project ,change it to library and then build aar with command "gradle aR",but the following error occurred。（flutter SDK 1.22.4 can do this without error,other version can not）

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 978

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 57s
```